# How to use PayloadLoggingInterceptor and SOAPLoggingInterceptor interceptors while consuming a third party web service

Tags: spring, maven, jaxb, webservice-client, spring-ws

In my application, I am consuming a third party web-service that is provided by my client.

I have developed my application on Spring and Hibernate framework and in one module I am consuming this third party web-service url. I have generated web-service stubs using

> javab2-maven-plugin

The maven plugin in declared as below in my pom.xml file :

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Package to store the generated file -->
                    <packageName>com.equifax.unsolicited.wsdl.stub</packageName>
                    <!-- Treat the input as WSDL -->
                    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                    <!-- Input is not XML schema -->
                    <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                    <!-- The WSDL file that you saved earlier -->
                    <schemaFiles>Duk_CIS_Send_CreditStatus.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                    <!-- The location of the WSDL file -->
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <!-- The output directory to store the generated Java files -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- Don't clear output directory on each run -->
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And I am using the auto-generated JAXB java classes to call the web service. I have created a service bean which call the web service :

```
@Service("unsolicitResponseService")
public class UnsolicitResponseServiceImpl  implements UnsolicitResponseService{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UnsolicitResponseServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;


    @Override
    public void sendUnsolicitResponse() {

        LOGGER.debug("Calling Duke Web Service to Send Unsolicit Response ... ");
        try{
            ObjectFactory objecFactory = new ObjectFactory();       

            CreditStatusMsgType creditStatusMessage = objecFactory.createCreditStatusMsgType(); 
            creditStatusMessage.setMessageHeader(createMessageHeader(objecFactory));

            //WRAP THE CLASS AS THE INSTANCE OF JAXBELEMENT OTHERWISE IT WILL THROW MISSING ROOTELEMENT ERROR
            JAXBElement<CreditStatusMsgType> creditStatusMessageJaxbElement = objecFactory.createSendCreditStatus(creditStatusMessage);

            //CREATE STRING WRITER TO LOG THE REQUEST           
            Object response = this.webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(creditStatusMessageJaxbElement);

            LOGGER.debug("Jumio Web Service Response Reponse :"+response);

            LOGGER.debug("Unsolicit Response sent to Duke Successfully.");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error("Exception generated while calling Web Service  to send unsolicit Response : "+ex.getLocalizedMessage(),ex);
        }       

    }
```

Below is the xml configuration where I have declared interceptors to log the request and response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <!-- DEFINE SOAP VERSION USED BY A WSDL -->
    <bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"> 
        <property name="soapVersion"> 

            <!-- FOR TEXT/XML -->   
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11"/>          
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <!-- LOCATION OF THE GENERATED JAVA FILEs -->    
    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.equifax.unsolicited.wsdl.stub"/>


    <!-- CONFIGURE THE SPRING WEB SERVICE -->
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"> 
        <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/> <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/> 
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/> 
        <property name="defaultUri"   value="https://partnerstg.duke-energy.com:4443/DukCISSendCreditStatus?wsdl"/> 
    </bean>


    <sws:interceptors>

        <bean id="jumioPeyLoadLoggingInterceptor" class="com.test.datasource.logging.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor">
        </bean>

        <bean id="jumioSOAPLoggingInterceptor" class="com.test.datasource.logging.interceptor.SOAPLoggingInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </sws:interceptors>

</beans>
```

And I also have added and new logging category to enable the logger level to DEBUG mode :

Above code is calling the web service successfully. But the interceptors are not getting called. So I am not able to log the XML request and response.

Here, I am assuming that, these interceptors will not work while consuming the service. Let me know if I am wrong here.

I am referring Spring Web Service from [HERE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d4e1413) . This website has given explanation interceptors while publishing a web-service.

Kindly let me know should we use this interceptors while consuming a web-service ? Or How should I print request and response which are JAXB-ELEMENT ?

Comment: of course they won't work as you have to register them with the `WebserviceTemplate` you are adding them to endpoints, which work if you have a server not for the client. Simply set the `interceptors` property of the `WebserviceTemplate`.

Comment: How do I set interceptor property of web service template ?

Comment: Like all the other properties you are setting on it... Why would it be different...

Comment: I am getting exception when I try to set interceptors property as below...        <property name="interceptors">    
   <ref bean="jumioPeyLoadLoggingInterceptor"/>
   <ref bean="jumioSOAPLoggingInterceptor"/>   
  </property>

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, it makes them unreadable. Wrap the elements in a `<list>` element and make sure that the beans are top-level beans (and not inside a `sws:interceptors` element...

Comment: Here, we can not use PayloadLoggingInterceptor. I am getting following error :  Cannot convert value of type [com.equifax.ic.datasource.jumio.ws.logging.interceptor.JumioPayloadLoggingInterceptor] to required type [org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor] for property 'interceptors[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: I may have to use PayloadValidatingInterceptor. But How should I log request/response in this interceptor ?

Comment: If you only want logging you don't need an interceptor. Just set the logger for `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing` to `TRACE` or `DEBUG`  and the requests and responses will be logged. And obviously you cannot use interceptors which are designed for endpoints (`EndpointInterceptor`) for the client (`ClientInterceptor`).

Comment: Thank You Deinum for the quick suggestions. You can post your feedback as answer below so I can accept it . I am also sharing my way which I have implemented to log the request and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding here solution which I have implemented. There are two ways by which we can implement this solution. I have implemented the second one from below list using JAXBContext and Marshaller.

**1> Log Request/Response By interceptor.**

We can not use **PayloadLoggingInterceptor** or **SOAPLoggingInterceptor** when we are consuming the web  service.

We need to use **ClientInterceptor** when we are consuming the web service. **ClientInterceptor** is implemented by **PayloadValidatingInterceptor** class which is used to intercept the request/response and validate the it based on xsd schema.

For that we need to provide interceptor reference as below :

```
<bean id="MyPayloadValidatingInterceptor" class="com.equifax.ic.datasource.jumio.ws.logging.interceptor.JumioPayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="file:WebContent/WEB-INF/schemas/account-balance-service.xsd" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="false" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="false" />
    </bean>
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"> 
        <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/> <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/> 
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/> 
        <property name="defaultUri"   value="https://partnerstg.duke-energy.com:4443/DukCISSendCreditStatus?wsdl"/>     
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>              
                <ref bean="MyPayloadValidatingInterceptor"/>                
            </list>         
        </property>     

    </bean>
```

**2> Log Request/Response by using JAXBContext**

This is the solution which I have implemented in my application as we should not use PayloadValidatingInterceptor only to log reqeust/response.

```
private void logJAXBRequest(JAXBElement<CreditStatusMsgType> creditStatusMessageJaxbElement){
        LOGGER.debug("Logging Web Service Request ...");

        StringWriter writer = null;
        StreamResult streamResult = null;
        StringBuffer buffer = null;
        try{
             writer = new StringWriter();
             streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

             JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreditStatusMsgType.class);
             Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
             marshaller.marshal(creditStatusMessageJaxbElement, streamResult);

             buffer = writer.getBuffer();

             LOGGER.debug("JAXB Webservice Request : "+ buffer.toString());

             writer.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            LOGGER.error("Exception generated while creating XML Logs of JAXB Request :",ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

He everyone, colleagues.
There are two main ways to show XML requests / responses:

1. First of all you have to add `log4j` dependency into your `pom.xml` file:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.17</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Then you **have to** place `log4j.properties` file into a classpath of your application. When I develop SOAP services I often use Spring WS Maven artefact. Unfortunately, a [usual](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) `resources` folder is not created from scratch and you have to create it manually. Then you place `log4j.properties` file there. The contents of log4j config depends on the approach you want to use (**see items below**). Obtained structure is following:
   [image]
3. Use a standard [Message Logging and Tracing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/common.html) approach & `log4j.properties` file. Nothing should be configured, developed, written except log4j config file contents. The contents of log4j config should be the following (use these contents as is):

   ```
   log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout
   log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
   log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=DEBUG

   log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=DEBUG

   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n
   ```
4. Use a `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` & `log4j.properties` file. Some config changes should be applied, but this approach is more flexible, as for me. First of all you have to add `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` into a `MessageDispatcherServlet` config file:

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"      xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="com.ln.springws"/>

       <sws:annotation-driven/>

       <sws:interceptors>
           <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />
       </sws:interceptors>

       <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="holiday" portTypeName="HumanResource"        locationUri="http://localhost:8080/holidayService/"        targetNamespace="http://spring-ws-holidays.com/hr/definitions">
           <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/hr.xsd"/>
       </sws:dynamic-wsdl>
       </beans>
   ```

   And at last place the following contents to `log4j.properties` file:

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%c] - <%m>%n
   ```
5. And as a result of both approaches you will have something like that in a console:
   [image]