# Spring Integration Log SOAP Message Content of int-ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

Could you tell me how to log the SOAP Message send/received of int-ws:outbound-gateway ?

I have tried

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="ais-outbound-gateway"
    request-channel="aisRequestChannel" reply-channel="aisResponseChannel"
    uri="http://localhost:8080/services/ONESHOT" 
    marshaller="aisMarshaller"        unmarshaller="aisMarshaller" /> 

<int:channel id="aisRequestChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>   
<int:channel id="aisResponseChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logChannel"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter expression="payload" id="logChannel" level="DEBUG"  />
```

But the payload is just java object, not SOAP message.

Best regards,

Comment: I am trying Marshaller.Listener and Unmarshaller.Listener. I think it is possible.

Comment: It does not work. It just can catch the java object before/after marshaller/unmarshaller, not the SOAP message :-(

Comment: I think your supposed to use the PayloadLoggingInterceptor . Talked about here in detail. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006048/how-to-use-payloadlogginginterceptor-and-soaplogginginterceptor-interceptors-whi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` supports `interceptor` injection:

```
<xsd:documentation>
    Reference to the bean definition of a ClientInterceptor.
</xsd:documentation>
```

So, you should implement your own `LoggingClientInterceptor`.

The logging ideas you can borrow from the existing `PayloadLoggingInterceptor`.